# Nginx status page not found

Tags: nginx, configuration, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to enable the Nginx status page on my Centos 7 server.

I installed Nginx from the EPEL repository, Nginx is built with staus page support:

```
[root@server ~]# nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o with-http_stub_status_module
with-http_stub_status_module
```

I have added a single config file /etc/nginx/conf.d/status.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

After restart, Nginx can't find the status page:

```
[root@server ~]# wget http://localhost/nginx_status
--2017-01-06 17:02:09--  http://localhost/nginx_status
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-01-06 17:02:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Every tutorial or example I found online says these are the steps I should take. Why do I keep getting a 404?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `server` block is missing a `listen` directive:

```
    listen [::]:80;
```

This directive tells nginx to answer IPv6 connections for that `server`. Unfortunately you omitted it, and only are answering IPv4 connections.

But, since `localhost` resolves to an IPv6 address (and in fact, IPv6 is the default protocol for everything on the Internet) your request is being processed by the default `server` block included with the default configuration, which *is* `listen`ing on IPv6.

You should be extra careful to ensure that all `server` blocks `listen` on IPv6 (mandatory, even if you do not have global IPv6 yet) and IPv4 (optional, only if you use IPv4).

Comment: Now, my 404 has changed to 403, one step at a time ;)

Comment: @verhage You didn't `allow ::1;` either :)

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it, I just added allow ::1; to my config and it works. I get it now, I didn't realize I had to also configure the IPv6 adresses.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any issues with your config and it's 404 rather than 403 which implies that it's not even read that config, so the debug steps I would go through are:

- have you restarted nginx ;)
- anything in the error_log?
- is nginx really listening on localhost? on ip4 and ip6? (`netstat -plnt`)
- try wget with the headers showing (`wget -SO- http://localhost/nginx_status`) perhaps something will show up
- is nginx really reading this config file? (is there another somewhere? make a deliberate typo and see if it barfs)
- is there more than one nginx? (getting stretched here, but stranger things have happened). Perhaps a restart isn't killing the old process?
- remove the server_name directive and try without it